# PHP - Select yes or no, yes causes a new input to appear

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure if this is possible or where to start to tackle it with, but I'm wanting to create a select with a yes or no option, which if yes is selected (form is yet to be submitted) a new date input appears below.

I'm thinking php is needed, but I'm very new to programming.. Any point into the right direction or basic explanation would be ideal!

So far I'm guessing it would be something like this...

```
    <select name="retrieveMarriage">
            <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Are you married?</option>
            <option value="Yes">yes</option>
            <option value="No">no</option>
    </select>
```

With the php being the confusing part.

```
if($_POST['retrieveMarriage'])
  ???
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to use PHP for this. Since you need to manipulate the DOM you gonna need to use Javascript.

Comment: William, what if JavaScript is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like JavaScript for that kind of stuff, personally.

```
<select name="retrieveMarriage" id="retrieveMarriage" onblur="myFunction()">
        <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Are you married?</option>
        <option value="Yes">yes</option>
        <option value="No">no</option>
</select>
<span id="newDate"></span>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(){
  var x=document.getElementById('retrieveMarriage').value;
  if(x == 'yes'){
     document.getElementById('newDate').innerHTML='<input type=text id="myNewField"/>';
     Whatever else you want to do...
  }
}
```